# Swipe horizontally to dismiss a view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, viewcontroller

I have a View Controller that appears as a pop up, that I presented it inside an other View Controller. I want this view controller when I swipe left/right to dismiss. How can I do this?

My View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class DelayAlertViewController: UIViewController {
        

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewShadow: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var delayAlertView: DelayAlertView!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerLabel: UILabel!
    
    private var message: String

    
    init(with message: String) {
        self.message = message
        super.init(nibName: "DelayAlertViewController", bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.definesPresentationContext = false
        self.delayAlertView.layer.borderWidth = 0.2
        self.delayAlertView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.viewShadow.addRoundedCornersShadow(radius: 1, width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 0.2)
        delayAlertView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        delayAlertView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        delayAlertView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
 
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add screen shot of your UI. It will be easy to understand. What exactly you want to do.

Comment: I edited my question with the screenshot.

Comment: so this Label with info icon is another view controller which is full screen which you want to dismiss when swipe left/right. correct? as it is already presented view controller, when swipe top to down it already dismiss. right?

Comment: This label with the info icon is the another view controller which is presented inside a view controller (the controller that appears behind). No, when I swipe down or top it doesn't do anything. But I want to swipe left or right, not top/down.

Comment: if you have presented, top to down is the default behavior to dismiss the presented view controller. anyway check the answer below. hope this is what you was looking for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, in viewDidLoad add this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    setupGestureRecognizers()
}
```

Then:

```
private func setupGestureRecognizers() {
    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeAction(swipe:)))
    leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
}
```

And finally target-action:

```
@objc func swipeAction(swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

**Update:**
If you want custom dismiss animation, for example left or right, try this code inside swipeAction:

```
@objc func swipeAction(swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
   let transition = CATransition()
   transition.duration = 0.5
   transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
   transition.type = CATransitionType.push
   transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
   self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
   self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: similarly add for right also & other directions if you want...

Comment: Yes it works, but when I swipe it, it goes down not the direction that I swipe it, how can I do this?

Comment: @ComputerEng : That is new question and I think for this you have to prepare custom view and make animation based on the touches listener...

Comment: @ComputerEng I updated answer, probably it can solve your additional question

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. 
One problem that I have with this solution: it swipes the fullscreen and not the view controller that is a small box (like a pop up). Do you know why it happens?

Comment: @ComputerEng can you share a code, where you present your DelayAlertViewController ?

Comment: @ComputerEng : how you call DelayAlertViewController?

Comment: let DelayAlertViewController = DelayAlertViewController(with: "message")
DelayAlertViewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
self.present(DelayAlertViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @ComputerEng This is strange behaviour. Probably, your parent view controller, which handles presentation of DelayAlertViewController is not wrapped in navigationController. Or vice versa. Try to replace self.dismiss with self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) inside swipeAction. And comment what happens

Answer (score 2):

There are two scenario.

***Scenario one:*** If your view controller is inside UINavigationController then you can use apple's built in API called interactivePopGestureRecognizer. Just add bellow line in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
```

despite after adding this line it does not work then add bellow line:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil;
```

If you want to trigger a specific method while popping then write bellow line:

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonPressed))
```

**Scenario two:** If your view controller is not inside UINavigationController then you can add UIPanGesture in viewDidLoad like bellow:

First delcare an instance named myPanGestureRecognizer like bellow:

```
var myPanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
```

Then add bellow lines in viewDidLoad:

```
myPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
            myPanGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(myPanGestureRecognizer)
```

Then write bellow method anywhere in your viewController:

```
@objc func handlePanGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: view)
        
        if recognizer.state == .ended {
            if velocity.x > 300 { // Adjust the value based on your requirement
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```